# How to setup camunda external task client

Tags: bpmn

I have a service tasks part of my bpmn file. I want to execute the service tasks asynchronously using camunda external task client. How to setup the external task client? Currently the service tasks execution are delegated to process engine itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for introduction see this [Camunda blog post](https://blog.camunda.com/post/2015/11/external-tasks/).

In short, you define the task implementation as "external" in your BPMN and define its topic.
Then, you create REST client with long polling which will fetch task execution info.

Luckily, you don't have to write the REST client by yourself, there are official implementations for Java and JS.

For a Java client, have a look at the examples on [GitHub repo](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-external-task-client-java).

More official info [here](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.10/user-guide/process-engine/external-tasks/) and [here](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.10/user-guide/ext-client/).